# Rails5.2.3から6.0.2へのアップグレード後に起動できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, webpack

`ActionText`を使用するために、`Rails`を`5.2.3`から`6.0.2`にアップグレードしたところ、
起動しなくなってしまいました。

`rails s`を実行すると下記のエラーのため、
`webpacker`がインストールされていないのが原因かと思っておりますが

◾️`rails s`でのエラー内容

```
/Users/〜/projects/blog/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/webpacker-8e8e7454e302/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:95:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /Users/〜/projects/eng_blog/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/〜/projects/blog/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
```

webpackerをインストールしようとしてもエラーがでます。
◾️`rails webpacker:install`でのエラー内容

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::InvalidConfigurationError: '{ default =>  }' is not a valid configuration. Expected '' to be a URL string or a Hash.
```

`bundle update`で各gemを最新版にすることは実施してみました。

DBの接続がうまくできていないのだと思うのですが、検索しても同様のエラーが
あまり見つからず、確認したらよい部分などでも、ご教授頂けますとありがたいです。

※`database.yml`の内容を追記致します。

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  # adapter: sqlite3
  # pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  # timeout: 5000

# development:
#   <<: *default
#   database: db/development.sqlite3

development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  # <<: *default
  # database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  # database: db/production.sqlite3
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Railsのアップグレードは比較的難しい作業です。[日本語版のドキュメント](https://railsguides.jp/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)などを見ながら必要なステップを一つずつこなしていくことになります。`6.0`へのアップグレードについては特に[こちら](https://railsguides.jp/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#rails-5-2%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89rails-6-0%E3%81%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89)を参照してください。

アップグレードを支援するスクリプトとして`rails app:update`というものがあります。こちらを利用するとステップバイステップでアップグレードを行うことができるため、必要そうであればぜひ利用してみてください。

その上で、データベースに関するエラーですが、[このコミット](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f3c68c59ed57302ca54f4dfad0e91dbff426962d)で導入されたエラーのようです。見たところ`config/database.yml`が正しくないために発生しているようです。質問に`config/database.yml`を含めていただくことは可能でしょうか。

---

`database.yml`にある`default: &default`の行をコメントアウトしてみてください。

Comment: ご回答いただき、誠にありがとうございます。

教えて頂いた手順を参照しながらアップグレードについては、
より慎重に行うようにしたいと思います。
`database.yml`の内容を質問に追加させていただきました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます、`webpacker`インストールでき無事に起動することができました。
※起動すると下記のエラーがでたので、
```Puma caught this error: Cannot load database configuration:
Unknown alias: default (Psych::BadAlias)```
`database.yml`の下記をコメントアウトすると問題なくなりました。
```production:
  <<: *default```

大変助かりました。